# How to make GQL queries in the new Google Cloud admin portal?

Tags: google-app-engine

I had developed an app several years ago on google app engine. At that time in the admin portal there was a section where I could run GQL queries against my database but I don't see any such section in the new `console.cloud.google.com` portal. I have tried googling a lot and can't find out how to make GQL queries against the db in this new portal. Is there a way to run GQL queries against the db in the new console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in the [Google Platform documentation](https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/entities/query/gql).

Comment: I don't agree with this edit.  It might help posterity if the format of the URL were clear.  The URL should look like this: https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/entities/query/gql